# I have confusion here in the limit whether I can take out the real function whose value is always greater or equal to 1 or not?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡\alpha (x_n,x_{n+1})d(x_n,x_{n+1})≤0 $$ where $\alpha (x_n,x_{n+1}): X×X→[1,\infty), x_n=T^n(x)$,as $T:X\to X$,X is complete metric space

Can we imply ,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡d(x_n,x_{n+1})≤0$$

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with anything else that you have mentioned?

Comment: Now check please.

Comment: Where is your parameter of $\alpha$? Also I believe if $d$ is the metric, shouldn't the limit just straight $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,x_{n+1}) = 0 \quad ?$$

Comment: Actually T is T- $\alpha$ orbitally admissible and this $\alpha$   is the function having value always greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: I'd personally appreciate it if you included a definition of "orbitally admissible" in the statement of the problem. I can't be the only one who isn't familiar with that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡ 1 \cdot d(x_n,x_{n+1}) \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}⁡\alpha (x_n,x_{n+1})d(x_n,x_{n+1})≤0$$
so yes, it does imply that. I am not sure why completeness even matters here, are you missing something?

Comment: Thank You very much. Completeness of the space is necessary for another result which can be followed by this argument only.

Comment: Don't we need to be sure the limit exists? But if $d$ is the metric and $\alpha > 1$ then doesn't $\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡\alpha (x_n,x_{n+1})d(x_n,x_{n+1})\leq0$ imply that $\lim_{n\to \infty}⁡\alpha (x_n,x_{n+1})d(x_n,x_{n+1})=0$? I think that might be significant. If $d$ could produce negative values then we would have to consider the possibility that $\alpha$ and $d$ are both oscillating and neither has a limit individually although their product is constant.